# Find the temperature of a graphics card via commandline in Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, temperature

Question: How can I find the temperature of my hardware via command line on Ubuntu?

---

Info:

I have a simulation that I've pushed off on to my work horse's graphics card(GTX465). I currently am in the position that I can only SSH into the machine. But I want to monitor the computer to make sure it isn't over heating (this happened last year.) Is there a way that I can query my computer for the temperature of its hardware, specifically the graphics card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the graphics card try

> nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp

and/or

> nvidia-smi -a

other sensors (cpu, chipset) may be accessible with [lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/)

Answer (score 4):

To get just the numeric temperature in Celsius, try:

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader
```